# After apply custom Master page to SP2013 site, hover sub-menu items list as main buttons

Tags: navigation

I am migrating a site collection from SP2010 to SP2013. The top menu is built with OOB navigation function. In site settings -> Navigation, we can see something like:

```
Global Navigation
  -- LV1 A
  -- LV1 B
  ----- LV2 C
  ----- LV2 D
```

When mouse hover on button B the submenu item C & D will show up.

After migrated to SP2013, I checked the site settings -> Navigation have same settings as old farm. However when I apply a custom Master page designed according to old site, the layout shows all 4 buttons A,B,C and D are listed in same level.

Here is part of my Master page:

```
<div class="menu">


                            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderTopNavBar" runat="server">
                                <SharePoint:AspMenu ID="TopNavigationMenu" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" DataSourceID="topSiteMap" AccessKey="&lt;%$Resources:wss,navigation_accesskey%&gt;" UseSimpleRendering="true" UseSeparateCss="false" Orientation="Horizontal" StaticDisplayLevels="3" AdjustForShowStartingNode="false" MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="3" SkipLinkText="">

                                </SharePoint:AspMenu>
                            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                            </div>
```

What can I do? Is it purely CSS issue? If possible please give me some reference to fix the CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry. I found the answer right after post the question.

My setting befores:

```
StaticDisplayLevels="3" MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="3"
```

It make the Level 3 items (C & D in my example above) a static display.

By change to this:

```
StaticDisplayLevels="2" MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="3"
```

It make the Level 3 dynamic display.